# How to tell if a web app uses code splitting

Tags: web-applications, code-splitting

How can a web developer tell if a web app at a given URL is using code splitting, such as that provided [by webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), rollup or other libraries?

Answer (score 3):

If using Google Chrome, you can take a look at the network tab of the developer tools.

If the application uses webpack code splitting, typically multiple JavaScript bundles are loaded, with hash codes for cache-busting added.

In the example below, there is a main JavaScript bundle `postList.blabla243fe.js`. This is loaded on page load. While the code is executed, another bundle `0.8a3dblabla.js` is loaded asynchronously.

[image: screenshot chrome dev tools network tab]